# SignalR scaleout with Redis backplane

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a site today using SignalR and it works fine. Now I'd like to implement Redis backplane so that I can scale the application over multiple servers.

The issue is that I keep additional information about the clients in a static *ConcurrentDictionary* such as name together with the client connectionId. This will of course not work when I scale out to multiple servers, and I was wondring if anyone had some best-practices to share before I build my own *"RedisDictionary"*?

Thank you

Comment: The only thing SignalR is storing in Redis is a message id and then it uses channels to get notified about new messages - so there is no connection Ids being stored in Redis.

Comment: I know that, and that is why I'm storing additional data in a _ConcurrentDictionary_. The question was, is there a best practice for moving a dictionary or hash table to Redis, as it needs to be shared cross web servers?

Comment: You can store them in Redis or you can use a Redis channel to broadcast to other servers. There are trade-offs in both cases (thread safety vs. looking the connection information up). It is hard to tell which one is better - it probably depends what's important - latency vs. consistency etc. which is application specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Redis backplane to publish and subscribe your individual client information.

Store the client information as a json string, and use the client name as your channel name. You can then subscribe everyone of your servers to the client. Anytime a change to the client is made, its updated information will be published and you can update your stored client information by deserializing the json string.

Comment: Can you please provide more info on how to implement this.